# Extracting a page from a pdf using a keyword

Tags: excel, pdf, search, vba

OK so im quite sure i cant do this with excel vb or for free even.

Im writing these macros for work, and one of them needs to be able to chose a pdf based on keywords.
Then go into the pdf, search either the titles of the pages or the text on the pages themselves using a different set of keywords.

When it finds the page that matches one of the keywords in the second set, it will extract the whole page, as is, to a single page pdf.

This can then be attached to email.

This will be only a small part of the purpose of the macro.
From what i understand, im probably going to have to find an SDK, pay for it, and write a separate program in C# or VisualBasic which is run when the macro needs.

I dont even need the code, maybe just a point in the right direction :D

Comment: Way too broad for SO I'm afraid. Just search for a PDF reader library that suits your needs, try it, and come back when you can't make it work. ("Keywords" is straightforward but note that "reading text" relies heavily on the 'quality' of the original PDFs, and may be impossible *at all* for a certain class of files.)

Comment: All the pdfs we are reading from are architectural drawings produced in CAD.  All the text is digital and can be selected.

Comment: I have found some free pdf reader libraries, and im in the process of getting ms visual studio, so will have a crack at C# an see if i can come up with something.

Answer (score 1):

In the end i got a program called pdftk.exe, free, and runs in command line.
With this i can export the Bookmarks listing to txtfile.
Search text file for string/keywords.
Jump down a line or two and grab associated page number.
Then use the same exe to extract that page and save as specific name, then my vba macro can grab that newly created 1 page pdf.

Ive seen code on this site for creating delays while another process is doing its thing, so i will try to implement that also.